# How to find the max file descriptors in Nuttx RTOS?

Tags: file-descriptor, rtos, px4, nuttx

I have a limited understanding of the Nuttx OS but have run into a limitation set by the config parameter *CONFIG_NFILE_DESCRIPTORS* using the PX4 stack. I'm using a Pixhawk 4 FCU board that has a STM32F76 processor. The firmware build (px4_fmu-v5) by default has that parameter set to 20. My understanding is that this is a soft limit that is applied to each module in the stack to limit its I/O. I can increase that limit without any visible issues so far but this raises a few concerns:

1. To what extent can I increase the limit of that parameter without causing any issues?
2. What are the potential consequences of exceeding that limit?
3. Is there a way to find the hard limit of the number of file descriptors (assuming this is specific to the processor type)? If not, can I monitor the usage of file descriptors per module over an NSH shell?

If this is over-simplifying the issue I'd appreciate any pointers in the right direction, but I preferably would not like to delve too deep into NuttX to understand how this generally works and what the limitations are here.

Comment: I have these questions too, Thorn.. Were you able to find an answer?